# How to format double resulting from stream collectors.averagingInt

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a map `Map<String,Double>` as a result of a grouping from java stream, which groups players by team and averaging their age as a solution for the task

> group the players by their respective teams and calculate the average age for each team.

Which is:

```
Map<String,Double> result = players.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Player::getTeam, Collectors.averagingInt(Player::getAge)));
```

The result map, when printed out for sample values shows something like:

```
result.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

output

```
Tottenham Hotspur=25.333333333333332
Liverpool=26.333333333333332
Manchester City=23.666666666666668
Arsenal=24.0
Chelsea=25.333333333333332
Manchester United=23.0
```

I want to limit the decimal part to two decimal places.

I have searched how to round a double which seems some how not trivial in java. But something like the below works for two decimal places:

```
double value   = 12.34567
double rounded = (double) Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
```

or alternativley converting it to string with:

```
String result = String.format("%.2f", value);
```

I'm ok with both solutions, but I don't know how to combine it in the stream while collecting. Is there a way to have the resulting map limited to two decimal places?

Comment: Use `printf` instead. You need to access the key and value separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to do it when printing:

```
result.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
  System.out.printf("%s: %.2f%n", entry.key, entry.value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Would have thought that there is a simple solution. But I am also satisfied with your suggestion, because I have to implement a printResult method anyway, which takes the map as a parameter.

Comment: There is no need for `entrySet()` nor `stream()`. Use `result.forEach((team, age) -> System.out.printf("%s: %.2f%n", team, age));` @rosojit how simple do you think it can get? You can chain the `forEach` call directly to the `collect` call if you don’t need the map for anything else. There is nothing in the code that is obsolete. You need to tell Java what you want to do and how you want it to be done.